# Git: How to compare file from working directory with same file in earlier commit?

Tags: git

Is there a way to compare the current state of a file (in working directory) with what the file looked like when it was commited (eg. five commits ago)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a `git log`, then copy SHA id of the commit. Then run `git diff` command with this id, for example:

```
git diff (sha-id) filename
```